# linked list insertion missing

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

hey I tried to build a linked list i Built two functions one for insert and one to create the list
but I have a problem in the insert i think its a memory problem
i cant find it 
    the code is working but somtimes it jumps to another functions for no reason but i dont know why

thanks for any help/idea

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

typedef struct {

    int num;
    struct List* next;

}List;
// i think the problem is in here cant find it :(((
List* insert(List* head, int num)
{
    List* temp = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    List* temp_head = head;
    temp->num = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp_head->next != NULL)
        {
            temp_head = temp_head->next;
        }
        temp_head->next = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
List* create_new_list(List* new_list)
{
    int number;
    printf("Enter numbers, to exit enter negative number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_list->num = number;
    new_list->next = NULL;
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    while (number >= 0)
    {
        new_list=insert(new_list, number);
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
    }
    return new_list;
}

int main()
{
    List* head= (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
    head=create_new_list(head);
}
```

Comment: `list* head = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));` -> `list *head = malloc (sizeof(List));` (note the `'L'` in `List`, or better `list *head = malloc (sizeof *head);` or even better, you need not allocate for `list`, e..g `list *head = NULL; head=create_new_list(&head);` and In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: You also may find (in order) [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) and then with a wrapper providing a `tail` pointer for O(1) insertions [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Comment: ok i tried making *head=NULL but didnt help
also why head=create_new_list(&head);?

Comment: The big problem is with `(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));` instead of `(list*)malloc(sizeof(List));` and of course `list* head` -> `List* head` and `list* insert(list* head, int num)` -> `List* insert(List* head, int num)`. **Check your L's**.

Comment: ok i tried but not helping ://

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you have a number of problems and your compiler should be telling you the exact line they are on. For starters you are missing the `struct List` in your definition of `List`, e.g.

```
typedef struct List {
    int num;
    struct List *next;
} List;
```

You next need to fix each location you have use `list` instead of `List` as the type, e.g.

```
List *insert (List *head, int num)
```

and

```
List *create_new_list (List *new_list)
```

and

```
    List *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

After making the changes you would have (**note:** I don't have `scanf_s` so `scanf` is used below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List {
    int num;
    struct List *next;
} List;

List *insert (List *head, int num)
{
    List *temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
    List *temp_head = head;

    temp->num = num;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = temp;
    else {
        while (temp_head->next != NULL)
            temp_head = temp_head->next;
        temp_head->next = temp;
    }

    return head;
}

List *create_new_list (List *new_list)
{
    int number;
    printf("Enter numbers, to exit enter negative number\n");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    new_list->num = number;
    new_list->next = NULL;
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    while (number >= 0)
    {
        new_list=insert(new_list, number);
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }
    return new_list;
}

void prnList (List *head)
{
    for (; head; head = head->next)
        printf (" %d", head->num);

    putchar ('\n');
}

int main()
{
    List *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
    head=create_new_list(head);
    prnList (head);
}
```

(**note:** I added the `prnList()` function)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ll_scanf
Enter numbers, to exit enter negative number
1 2 3 4 5 -1
 1 2 3 4 5
```

**Alternative - Avoid Allocating for `head`**

You can simply use `head` in `main()` with automatic storage duration rather than allocating. For example, you can do:

```
int main()
{
    List head = { .num = 0 };
    create_new_list(&head);
    prnList (&head);
}
```

This simply frees you from having to later `free(head)` and otherwise and can be passed to any function that needs it just as if it were allocated. **Note:** you do not assign the return from `create_new_list(&head);` if you take this route as `head` above is an instance of the struct, not a pointer to `List`.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Also note: the `'*'` goes with the variable name and not the type (generally). Why? Because:

```
List* a, b, c;
```

does NOT declare three pointers to `List`, instead it declares a single pointer to `List` (`a`) and two instances of `struct List` (`b, c`). Using:

```
List *a, b, c;
```

makes that clear.